# MS SQL with Spark Scala

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark

Please provide solution for following issue
I am using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver to access data in spark project with following code,

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1/sparkDB")
      .option("dbtable", " SELECT * FROM test_table" )
      .option("user", "sa")
      .option("password", "User@123456")
      .load()
```

But I get following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
The TCP/IP connection to 
the host 127.0.0.1/sparkDB, port 1433 has failed. Error: 
"127.0.0.1/sparkDB. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an 
instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP 
connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not 
blocked by a firewall.".
```

where as my firewall is off.

Comment: try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Hi @Yakout i used also localhost , same issue was found

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\\sparkDB")
      .option("dbtable", " (SELECT * FROM test_table) AS Q" )
      .option("user", "sa")
      .option("password", "User@123456")
      .load()
```

or

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
      .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;instancename=sparkDB")
      .option("dbtable", " (SELECT * FROM test_table) AS Q" )
      .option("user", "sa")
      .option("password", "User@123456")
      .load()
```